# UISearchBar doesn't resize when frame is resized in IOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code, this is a part of it,
that is supposed to setup a toolbar, and during screen
rotations it's removing it, resizing the search box
and then displaying it, except it doesn't resize properly ...

(I cannot find the reason it won't resize, frame gets resized)

There are also other buttons to the left and right of the search
that are defined as 
UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, and UIBarButtonItemStylePlain,
that "should" get automatically repositioned when search bar resizes ...

All of this is done without storyboards, programatically.

```
in loadView:

    LtoolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    LsearchBox = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    LsearchBox.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    LsearchBox.delegate = self;
    LsearchContainer = [UIView new];
    [LsearchContainer addSubview:LsearchBox];
    LbtnSearchBox = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:LsearchContainer];
    [LtoolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: LbtnSearchBox, nil] animated:NO];

in viewDidLoad I add the toolbar (see rotate below)
     [self.view addSubview:LtoolBar];

in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:

        [LtoolBar removeFromSuperview];

in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation))
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 30);
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation))
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 30);

    [LsearchContainer setFrame:bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:LtoolBar];
    [LtoolBar sizeToFit];
```

Thanks for any help!

---

Update 1:

I was able to fix this by adding a resize animation after the last line
depending whether frame was 280 or 360 and setting it to size + 1 ...

Terrible hack but it resizes the Search Bar ...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
     animations:^{ [LsearchContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 281, 30)]; } completion:nil];
```

I would still like to know how to fix it without the hack ...

---

Update 2:

Instead of the animation this also fixes the issue:

```
    [LsearchBox removeFromSuperview];
    [LsearchContainer addSubview:LsearchBox];
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Were you still looking for help in regards to this or did you get it figured out?

Comment: Although removing and re-adding fixes the issue, I would like to know if there's a better way to do this ... ?