# UISearchBar not resizing on phone rotation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I am having an issue where my UISearchBar does not resize on phone rotation unless I touch on the search bar so that it has focus (see images below).

The search bar is created and added to a UIMapView as a subview. See code.

Searchbar creation:

```
public UISearchController DefineSearchController()
{
    _searchResultsController = new SearchResultsVC(_mapView);
    _searchResultsController.searchItemSelected += PlaceSelect;


    _searchUpdater = new SearchResultsUpdator();
    _searchUpdater.UpdateSearchResults += _searchResultsController.Search;

    //add the search controller
    var searchController = new UISearchController(_searchResultsController)
    {
        SearchResultsUpdater = _searchUpdater
    };

    var scb = searchController.SearchBar;

    scb.SizeToFit();
    scb.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;

    var img = UIImage.FromBundle("tabSpace");
    scb.SetBackgroundImage(img, UIBarPosition.Top, UIBarMetrics.Default);

    var textField = scb.ValueForKey(new NSString("searchField")) as UITextField;
    if (textField != null)
    {                
        var backgroundView = textField.Subviews[0];

        if (backgroundView != null)
        {
            backgroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            backgroundView.Layer.BorderColor = AppColour.PersianBlue.GetUIColour().CGColor;
            backgroundView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            backgroundView.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundView.ClipsToBounds = true;

        }

    }

    var localEnterPoI = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("placeHolderSearchForLocation", "Enter a PoI to search for");
    scb.Placeholder = localEnterPoI; 

    searchController.Delegate = new SearchControllerDelegate();
    searchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;

    return searchController;
}
```

Added to the subview:

```
        //Define Search Controller
        _mapSearchManager = new MapSearchManager(_mapView);
        _searchController = _mapSearchManager.DefineSearchController();
        var scb = _searchController.SearchBar;
        _mapView.AddSubview(scb);

        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new NSLayoutConstraint[]{
            scb.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_mapView.TopAnchor, 30),
            scb.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_mapView.LeadingAnchor, 10),
            scb.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_mapView.LeadingAnchor, -10),
        });
```

I heave search extensively and was only able to find one similar issue:
[UISearchBar doesn't resize when frame is resized in IOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963980/uisearchbar-doesnt-resize-when-frame-is-resized-in-ios-11)

I implementing both of suggestion but it didn't make any difference.

Has anyone else encounted this or know what a possible solution might be.

Cheers

[image: Portait Mode]

[image: Rotated]

[image: Rotated with focus]

Comment: How do you set the SearchBar's Frame or constraints? Do you update its Frame when it begins to edit?

Comment: Currently there are no restraints.Although I did try adding constraints to see if it made a difference and unfortunately it didn't.  Constraints were from mapview. leading edge to searchbar leading edge, trailing edge to trailing edge and top to top.

Comment: It seems weird. If you set the correct constraints, it will layout when rotation. How is your mapView(only frame)? You can try to post this view's all constraints he help us find the issue.

Comment: Edit post to include constraints